# In Angular2 how to add a class to only the first row

Tags: angular

I want to add a css class based on certain conditions.

In the below code I want to add `RowHeaderCSS` class to the first row of the table, but it does work. Can anyone help me on this?

```
<tr *ngFor="let dataObject of dataCollection;let isFirstRow=(index==1?true:false)" [ngClass]="{'RowHeaderCSS':isFirstRow)}">
        <td scope="row">{{dataObject.SNO}}</td>
        <td Overdue-Bucket-Template>{{dataObject.MONTH01}}</td>
        <td Overdue-Bucket-Template>{{dataObject.MONTH02}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Why didn't you use inline styles?

Comment: yes i can. But with inline style how i can implement this condition?

Comment: Incidently, it might be worth investigating the `th` HTML tag. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Angular has the local variable `first` for all `ngFor` loops which will do what you want

```
<tr *ngFor="let dataObject of dataCollection; let isFirstRow=first" [ngClass]="{'RowHeaderCSS' : isFirstRow}">
    <td scope="row">{{dataObject.SNO}}</td>
    <td Overdue-Bucket-Template>{{dataObject.MONTH01}}</td>
    <td Overdue-Bucket-Template>{{dataObject.MONTH02}}</td>
</tr>
```

https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

> **Local Variables**
>
> NgFor provides several exported values that can be
>   aliased to local variables:
>
> 1. `index` The index of the current item in the iterable.
> 2. `first` True when the item is the first item in the iterable.
> 3. `last` True when the item is the last item in the iterable.
> 4. `even` True when the item has an even index in the iterable.
> 5. `odd` True when the item has an odd index in the iterable.

Comment: Hi this works fine after little change 
<tr *ngFor="let dataObject of dataCollection;let isFirstRow=first" [ngClass]="{'RowHeaderCSS': isFirstRow }">

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr *ngFor="let dataObject of dataCollection; let i = index" [ngClass]="{ i == 0 ? 'RowHeaderCSS' : ''}">
    <td scope="row">{{dataObject.SNO}}</td>
    <td Overdue-Bucket-Template>{{dataObject.MONTH01}}</td>
    <td Overdue-Bucket-Template>{{dataObject.MONTH02}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr *ngFor="let dataObject of dataCollection;let [ngClass]="{'RowHeaderCSS':isFirstRow(index))}">
        <td scope="row">{{dataObject.SNO}}</td>
        <td Overdue-Bucket-Template>{{dataObject.MONTH01}}</td>
        <td Overdue-Bucket-Template>{{dataObject.MONTH02}}</td>
</tr>

isFirstRow(index: number) : boolean{
  return index === 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a slightly different syntax:

```
<tr *ngFor="let dataObject of dataCollection; let i=index" [class.RowHeaderCSS]="i==0">
    <td scope="row">{{dataObject.SNO}}</td>
    <td Overdue-Bucket-Template>{{dataObject.MONTH01}}</td>
    <td Overdue-Bucket-Template>{{dataObject.MONTH02}}</td>
</tr>
```